# How can a call a user that is engaged on another call in Skype?

Tags: skype

Is there any way I can get a call to a user is engaged on another call to a different Skype user?

For instance:
A is on a call with B, and then C wants to call to A; they cannot because A is engaged on a call.
Is there anything C can do to get A's attention, interrupt A's call, etc so that they may start a call with A?

Comment: I don't think that this question has any practical use. It would be a pretty bad idea to have this "feature" implemented.

Comment: IM? text message? email?

Comment: yea IM works but still. I was just wondering if there's anyway at all to interrupt A's call and pick up C's call. lolz I know it's pretty bad idea if it has this feature but i was just wondering if there's such technical IT that could make this possible for those who know only.